# Return a value from the first row of a data frame where all remaining rows meet a certain criteria

Tags: r

I have about 800 linear models that all follow the same pattern, they are linear for most lengths, however at a certain point it can start to take off exponentially (however not always).  I'd like to identify the point where this starts to happen (if there is one).  For example:

```
df <- data.frame(Length = c(10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100),
                 Error = c(0.012, -0.013, 0.010,0.001,-0.005, 0.06, 0.0021, 0.07, 0.10, 0.15))


Length    Error
10        0.012
20        -0.013
30        0.010
40        0.001
50        -0.005
60        0.06
70        0.0021
80        0.07
90        0.10
100       0.15
```

I would like to identify the value of the length where the linear model breaks down.  So I would like the length where after it, ALL errors are >0.05.

So in this case I would like to identify the length value of 70 , because all lengths we have > 70 have an error >0.05 (Will always be in positive direction, so I'm not concerned with |error| > 0.05 ).

Comment: Can you provide a code sample which shows the change?

Comment: "So I would like the length where after it, ALL errors are >0.05."  at 70 it is 0.0021, so all errors above 60 are not > 0.05.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is the maximum value where the column is less than 0.05

`newdata <- df[order(Length),] 
tail(subset(newdate, error < 0.05)$Length,1)`

This is should spit out 70 but I am assuming that the length is already in order

Comment: Ah, I didn't think about it from that perspective.  They are not all in order.  But I could maybe do something like:  

edit: bad formatting here, so I will put an answer below.  Let me know.

Comment: Check the edit I made to the answer.  Sort then check

Comment: I think I could just do

    max(df$length[df$error <0.05]) 

right?

Answer (score 0):

Jenks who answered before got me thinking, and I think a fairly simple solution would be.

```
df <- data.frame(Length = c(10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100),
                Error = c(0.012, -0.013, 0.010,0.001,-0.005, 0.06, 0.0021, 0.07, 0.10, 0.15))
x <- df$error <0.05
max(df$length[x])
```